# Mixing words from wordlist and making new wordlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to do mixing of words from wordlist and creating newwordlist

this is my wordlist

```
Nice
have fun
its cool
_
make
quote
backtick
_
jobs
public
over
```

what i am trying to do is mixing those words and want output like this.

```
Nice
make
jobs
_
have fun
quote
public
_
its cool
backtick
over
```

this is what i've tried

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    wordlist= f.read().splitlines()

newwordlist = []

for x in range(2):
   newx = wordlist[x]
   newwordlist.append(newx)
```

Comment: What do you mean by mixing? Do you want some kind of randomness or just transposing?

Answer (score 0):

You can just basically "transpose" them with `zip`:

```
with open('wordlist.txt','r') as f:
    wordlist= list(zip(*[i.splitlines() for i in f.read().split('_')]))
```

If there are no underlines:

```
with open('wordlist.txt','r') as f:
    wordlist= list(zip(*[f.readlines()[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(f.readlines()),3)]))
```

And do new file:

```
...
with open('wordlist2.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write('_'.join(['\n'.join(i) for i in wordlist]))
```

Comment: and what if i dont have underscore ? in list and only words ? which i want mixed ?

Comment: tried ur code , doesnt work , 
this is my wordlist http://rophoto.es/wordlist.txt

Answer (score 0):

With underscores you could use the concept proposed by U9-Forward

```
with open('wordlist.txt','r') as f:
    wordlist = list(zip(*[i.splitlines() for i in f.read().split('_\n')]))

with open('newwordlist.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write('\n_\n'.join(['\n'.join(i) for i in wordlist]))
```

*U9 was really close, just the newlines became issues*

---

If you have just have a list of words and no underscores, you could use `random.shuffle`.

```
from random import shuffle

with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
    shuffle(words)    # shuffles words randomly

with open('newwordlist.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write('\n'.join(words))
```